# Getting 0 for output instead of expected calculation

Tags: java

I keep on getting 0.0 for my outputs. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

My user input for the first few sections is OK, and the number comes up correctly. Its only when asking for the total and subsequent math that I get 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeShop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Welcome Message and name prompt
        String username;

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        username = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Byte Code Coffee Shop," + username + "!");

        //Menus
        System.out.println("Here is our menu.");
        System.out.println("1. Coffee $1.50");
        System.out.println("2. Latte $3.50");
        System.out.println("3. Cappuccino $3.25");
        System.out.println("4. Espresso $2.00");

        //What item do they want?
        int product_Number;
        System.out.println("Please enter the item number.");
        Scanner item = new Scanner(System.in);
        product_Number = item.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You selected item " + product_Number);
        double product;

        if (product_Number == 1) {
            product = 1.50;
        }
        if (product_Number == 2) {
            product = 3.50;
        }
        if (product_Number == 3) {
            product = 3.25;
        }
        if (product_Number == 4) {
            product = 2.00;
        } else {
            product = 0.00;
        }

        //Quantity of item
        int quantity;
        System.out.println("How many would you like?");
        Scanner amount = new Scanner(System.in);
        quantity = amount.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You want " + quantity + " of them!");
        //Testing Product
        double total = quantity * product;
        System.out.println("Total before discount and tax is " + total);

        double nuTotal;
        //Discount/Tax
        if (total >= 10) {
            nuTotal = total - (total * .1);
        } else {
            nuTotal = total;
        }
        System.out.println("Your total with discount is " + nuTotal);
        double totalTax = nuTotal * .07;
        System.out.println("Your total with tax is " + totalTax);

        System.out.println("Thank you " + username + "! Please stop by again!");

    }
}
```

Comment: so put in more debug output and track down exactly which line is "losing" your values...

Comment: Please post good quality code - this indentation hurts eyes!

Comment: @kittyPL:  Fixed the indentation.  It's really not difficult to do with IntelliJ or any auto-formatting IDE, so what's the harm in taking two minutes to do that?

Comment: Y'know, it would be Really Nice if SO could add simple text indenters to its functionality. It's a somewhat ugly chunk of code, but not _that_ much worse than the simple control-K indent-by-4 operation.

Comment: @Makoto if its so simple, do it before posting code here. YOU are asking for help, not me.

Comment: @kittyPL: Well, for what few questions I've asked, I usually do format the questions pretty nicely.  For the others, I don't mind using IntelliJ to fix the formatting.  It exerts more energy complaining about it than actually fixing it, IMO.  That's all.

Answer (score 5):

Your `if` statement is broken - the last statement is always* guaranteed to fire, giving you `0.0`.

You should group them together as an `if-else if-else` statement, as such:

```
if (product_Number == 1) {
    product = 1.50;
} else if (product_Number == 2) {
    product = 3.50;
} else if (product_Number == 3) {
    product = 3.25;
} else if (product_Number == 4) {
    product = 2.00;
} else {
    product = 0.00;
}
```

Also, your total statement is wrong, too - you only print out the `tax` value and not the `total + tax` value.

<sup>*: If you chose 4, then it would actually work.  But that's because the choice of 4 is attached to the `else`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could also go about it like this:

```
    double product = 0;

    if (product_Number == 1) {
        product = 1.50;
    }
    if (product_Number == 2) {
        product = 3.50;
    }
    if (product_Number == 3) {
        product = 3.25;
    }
    if (product_Number == 4) {
        product = 2.00;
    }
```

Giving the variable product value null (0) and then giving it a new value further down the code.

Comment: At that point, you're now checking every single possible block regardless of if the value is set.  A fair bit less desirable than an if-else if-else, or even `switch`.